# Is there an option to disable PHP logging to command prompt

Tags: php, windows, cmd, command-prompt

When I run `php -S 127.0.0.1:80` in the [command-prompt](/questions/tagged/command-prompt) it keeps logging stuff going on, but can I disable that?

I'm still a beginner to [php](/questions/tagged/php) and I send long values but I feel like the logs are slowing it down.

Comment: Your question does currently provide sufficient information to properly determine the best course of ation for your scenario. Which settings are you using for logging? because I'd suggest changing those before resorting to just appending `1>NUL 2>&1` to your command. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62238710/edit) to provide more information.

Comment: The problem I have is with command prompt not PHP because printing long strings some times takes a second or more which is a lot to me, all I'm asking to do is to disable that so when I run the php server I don't get anything printed in the command prompt to save time

Comment: I was just worried if I could break anything related to my app

Comment: So what happens when "just appending `1>NUL 2>&1` to your command"?

Comment: Yes, that worked.
you can repost it as an answer so I can approve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following redirection of default handles `1>`, (StdOut), and `2>`, (StdErr), should generally prevent output to the Command Prompt window.

```batch-file
php -S 127.0.0.1:80 1>NUL 2>&1
```

*I would however strongly advise that you take a look at the PHP settings you're using for logging, rather than relying on this method.*